# postgreSQL how to human read WAL files

Tags: postgresql, wal

due to a bad foreign key, we had some non written inserts in to database, but i have the wal files generated when this actions, just a few, so im wondering if is possible to decrypt them and read the original query values. i cant replay anithing because database owner just can give me those wal files.

thanks in advance.

I have seen the pg_waldump but no example of how to use and wanted to know if there is something just to make this bin readable

I would have something at output like "insert blabla into blabla"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally with the plugin for vscode hex editor, i have been able to read SOME values inside each wal file. The problem is data is not so ordered, like i have a huge list of emails, then a huge list of messages, so i cant be sure to which email correspond wich message, and also there were boolean values that i cant find, despite of message. but yes, the data is here. in bad way but bit readable

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible, since WAL contains low-level binary information that cannot readily be translated into SQL statements. Moreover, it is unclear what "non-written inserts" are – if they were not written, they were probably not logged in the WAL either.

Without a base backup, WAL files are pretty useless.

Comment: Thanks a lot dor your answer and time :)